# Joomla include -- what and where is the file?

Tags: joomla, include

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="foot"/>
```

What file does the code above include in joomla and where is it located?

I have grep'ed a whole site for a string that I know has to be in the file called by that line of code... and I haven't found it.

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a template position called foot. The jdoc:include is the code used by the joomla framework to create the position for modules in the template. So if you publish a module in the position "foot", you see it appear in that place holder for the "foot" position.

Comment: You don't edit it as it's not a module. It's a position for modules. Unless you have a module specifically published in the "foot" position, nothing will appear there in your browser. What is it that you're trying to remove/do with your site?

Comment: well that module does generate a string, some html, and that is inserted into the position "foot". I'm just looking to change the content of what it's inserting.

Comment: oh nvm... i see now.. I just go to edit modules in my admin then edit the custom output.

Comment: In which case you most likely have a module published in that position. Check the modules section in the joomla backend for a module published in the foot position... Ah glad you found the module!